# Get data from table based on json

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a column 'sample_column' which is jsonb.

Can anyone tell me how can I select data based on 'sample_column' in postgresql?

Example of data in sample_column:    {"a": []}
                                     {"a": [1,2,3]}

I want to get all data if sample_column has value {"a": []}

Here is what I have done: `Select * from sample_table where sample_column =   '{"a": []}'`

I am getting ERROR:invalid input syntax for type json.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If the `a` key is the only differentiator, couldn't you just do `select * from sample_table where sample_column->'a' = '[]'`?

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Also, what can I do if i have more keys?

Comment: Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `a` key is the differentiator, the following should do:

```
select * from sample_table where sample_column->'a' = '[]';
```

If you're dealing with more keys, you may have to use an `AND` or an `OR` operator, depending on what you are trying to do. The following is an illustration:

```
-- Create table and insert some rows in it
create table sample_table (sample_column jsonb);
insert into sample_table values ('{"a": []}'), ('{"b": 2, "a": [2,3]}'), ('{"c": 20}');

-- Use an OR operator to get rows where the value for the "b" key is greater 1
-- or the value for the "c" key is equal to 20.
select * from sample_table where sample_column->'b' > '1' or sample_column->'c' = '20';
```

You should get something like:

```
 {"a": [2, 3], "b": 2}
 {"c": 20}
```

To get all data of sample_column that have value other than {"a": []}, you can do the following:

```
select * from sample_table where sample_column != '{"a": []}'::jsonb;
```

Here, the added `::jsonb` casts the characters into `jsonb` type, which should make the comparison possible.

I hope this proves useful.